How to extract Android 13+ ROMs (system.img and other partitions)?
I'm trying to unpack Android 13/14 ROMs from a set of different vendors but it seems that all images using Android 13+ have some changes in how the filesystem images are built.  Using simg2img (simg2img ./system.img ./system.raw) I'm capable of converting the sparse system.img file of a ROM correctly into some unknown image format.
Inspecting the converted image shows that it no partition is detected. For Android version below 12 usually it was an ext4 partition.
file ./system.raw
./system.raw: data

However, the file command shows that it is recognized as a data partition. So I guessed that we need to identify some offset to be able to mount or convert this image correctly. I tried to identify if the partition is a F2FS image (following this tutorial) but wasn't successful in identifying the magic bytes for F2FS.
Does anyone know how to mount or convert Android 13+ ROMs? Are there any good script out there to automate it?
